# Slow apache2 service start on boot

Tags: server, apache2

If I reboot my machine, it takes over 5 minutes for the apache2 service to start.

I can always start it manually as soon as I can through the command line:

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 start
```

This starts the service instantaneously and my server is up.
I would like the service to start on boot as soon as possible.
Any ideas why it takes > 5mins to start on its own?

EDIT:

After some digging, I found out about the very conveninent command

```
systemd-analyze blame
```

which revealed that networking.service took 5mins 649ms!
In the end, it had nothing to do with apache2 service,more something to do about a service waiting to be initialized before apache

Comment: This may not linked to Apache but maybe it is waiting on another service like network. Are you sure that your server has a static ip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to study your logs in /var/log/; they'll tell you how long each service apache2 takes, before apache gets it's turn. If there are services with problems, you may want to solve problems or disable unneeded services. If there are services, which are ok, but just take very long time, you may want to change the order.

In /etc/rc2.d you'll find apache2, maybe you want to make it start earlier in case it should have been put late in the list (depends on the number after S, like S01rsyslog starts before S05cups, which makes sense. Make sure you don't start apache before network is up.